# React parsing JSON data with multiple worded identifier

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to access JSON data however the JSON identifiers use multiple words. The JSON data is formatted like:

```
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (5min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-04-02 16:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "5min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (5min)": {
        "2020-04-02 16:00:00": {
            "1. open": "109.5600",
            "2. high": "110.3200",
            "3. low": "109.4300",
            "4. close": "110.0400",
            "5. volume": "421231"
        },
//...
```

I use:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ StockInfo: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
```

to fetch the data.

```
console.log(StockInfo["Meta Data"])
```

This line works to access the data however with

```
console.log(StockInfo["Meta Data"]["1. Information"]
```

I receive the error: TypeError: Cannot read property '1. Information' of undefined. Also,

```
console.log(StockInfo[0]) //or
console.log(StockInfo["Meta Data"][0]
```

also gives the same error.

Comment: where are you logging these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because  render function gets called before componentDidMount as well as you are making an asynchronous call. So in render do a check if its available.

```
 render() {
    if (!this.state.StockInfo["Meta Data"]) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>
         {this.state.StockInfo["Meta Data"]["1. Information"]}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dnzze3